# How do I filter specific number using `np.where`

Tags: python, numpy

Case

[image]

so I have an array like these, and how do I extract the green number from the array?

The output that I wanted :

```
[11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25, 31, 33, 35]
```

My code to make the array:

```
a = np.arange(start=11, stop=36, step=1)
```

My code for filtering:

```
print(a[np.where((a % 2 == 1))])
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to extract values from the array on the basis of location in the array or on the basis of the value?
The best way to ask a question on here is to provide both the input data and the desired output.

Comment: thx, i'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach using just lists:

```
from functools import reduce

board = [[x * 5 + 10 + y for y in range(1, 6)] for x in range(0, 5)]

reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list(zip(*board[0:5:2]))[0:5:2])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(11, 21, 31, 13, 23, 33, 15, 25, 35)
```

Alternatively, you could use something like:

```
[board[y-1][x-1] for x in range(1,6) for y in range(1,6) if x * y % 2 == 1]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[11, 21, 31, 13, 23, 33, 15, 25, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I answered your question..

```
array = np.array(

              [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],

              [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],

              [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],

              [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],

              [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])

filter1 = array[:, [0, 2, 4]]
filter2 = filter1[[0, 2, 4], :].flatten()

>>[11 13 15 21 23 25 31 33 35]
```

Comment: is there a way to filter it with from 1 dimension array? cz im using np.arange  in this case.

My array code : a = np.arange(start=11, stop=36, step=1)

Thanks for ur solution, but i hope u can answer this question :))

Comment: you can reshape your 1D array using "array = array.reshape(-1, 5)" and proceed with the above solution.